# Maximum CreateProcessWithLogonW and NetUserAdd

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have written a small function that will load multiple instances of an
executable using CreateProcessWithLogonW

the pseudo-code:

```
for ( i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
 sprintf(user,"user%i",i);
 sprintf(pass,"pass%i",i);
 if(NetUserGetInfo(user,pass)==NOT_FOUND) { NetUserAdd(user,pass); }
 aaProcessCreateWithLogin("prog.exe",user,pass);
 }
```

it works fine, except , it is limited to 32 instances -
additional instances fail -

Is there a limit to the number of users that can launch
processes at the same time  ?

Thanks

Ash

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(VS.85).aspx):

> There is a limit to the number of
>   child processes that can be created by
>   this function and run simultaneously.
>   For example, on Windows XP, this limit
>   is `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS*4`. On Windows
>   2000, this limit is
>   `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`. However, you may
>   not be able to create this many
>   processes due to system-wide quota
>   limits.

I've tested `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` on Windows XP and it is 64, so maybe you are hitting the 'system-wide quota limits'.

[This post](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/2006-01/msg00130.html) suggests using a combination of [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) and [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx) instead to avoid hitting these limits.